# Find a special kind of buttons with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I want to click in one button from the linkedin page with this code:

```
<a class="vcard-button bt-connect bt-primary" href="#"><span>&nbsp;</span>Connect</a>
```

With this code driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class='vcard-button bt-connect bt-primary']")  i can find the elements but when i try to click them i get a message saying that the object isn't clickable. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

From the limited information that you have provided seems like the problem is because of `find_elements`, note the **'s'**

This:

```
code driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class='vcard-button bt-connect bt-primary']")
```

returns a list of webelements.

So what you might want to do is

```
connect = code driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class='vcard-button bt-connect bt-primary']")
connect.click()
```

Or

```
connect_buttons = code driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class='vcard-button bt-connect bt-primary']")
# Assuming the first index in the returned list of web elements contains the Webelement
# You want to interact with 
connect_buttons[0].click()
```

Comment: I alredy did that. I try to run click() on each element of the list. The problem is that selenium say's that the element isn't clickable anyway.

Comment: Share the page link, I guess there is some other element overlapping it.

Comment: http://www.linkedin.com/people/pymk?trk=nmp-pymk-new_pymk_title By changinf the css selector to "a.vcard-button.bt-connect.bt-primary" i can get the first page to work but after i scroll down to get the other ones i can't click them anymore

Comment: You need to find the elements again, once you scroll down and load new contacts to connect.