# Clicking special button with selenium and python

Tags: python, css, button, selenium, click

i'm trying to click the connect button the the "people you may know" page from the linkedin (http://www.linkedin.com/people/pymk?trk=nmp-pymk-new_pymk_title)

The html code for this buttons are:

```
<a class="vcard-button bt-connect bt-primary" href="#"><span>&nbsp;</span>Connect</a>
```

I tryed to do this:

```
buttons=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class='vcard-button bt-connect bt-primary']")
```

and then for each element of the list call the function click(). However i keep geting the same error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u'unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (473, 14). Other element would receive the click: <input name="keywords" id="main-search-box" class="search-term" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search for people, jobs, companies, and more...">
(Session info: chrome=30.0.1599.101)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.2,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)'
```

Someone know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You repeat your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716052/find-a-special-kind-of-buttons-with-selenium-and-python

Comment: Sounds like the element in question isn't visible, or is visible but is behind some other element. Also, I'm thinking that LinkedIn's [user agreement](http://www.linkedin.com/legal/user-agreement) has some terms that might forbid this sort of bot crawling (ctrl+f for "scrape").

Comment: so there's no way i can do this?

Comment: clean up your css selector as well - use `a.vcard-button.bt-connect.bt-primary` instead.

Comment: It worked in the first case but then it stop working :/

Comment: Yeah, the problem is after i scroll the page down. For the clicking problem that works. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# You need a mouse to hover the span elements here
self.mouse = webdriver.ActionChains(self.driver)    

# You need get the element from its xpath:
buttons=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class='vcard-button bt-connect bt-primary']")

# Then you hover on span element by mouse and click on it:
self.mouse.move_to_element(buttons).click().perform()
```